# Extract total occurance of billing date within subscription period MySQL

Tags: mysql

Trying to find the number of time the billing date occurs inside the entire subscription period.

For example, if subscription period is 26-01-2015 and 24-09-2016 so the billing date is 27th of each month. Hence the query should return 20 as the number of bill cycles completed.

Comment: What? "day to be searched/counted is 27 the query should return 20"

Comment: With simple words you want to count day number 27 within a date range of 26-01-2015 and 24-09-2016?

Comment: What about February 29th?

Comment: mine answer should also handle leap years just fine @TimBiegeleisen so the topicstarter shoudn't worry about February 29th

Answer (score 1):

You need to make use of a MySQL number generator to generate the dates series.

**Query**

```
SELECT 
 COUNT(*) AS 'number of days'
FROM ( 

  SELECT 
   '2015-01-26' + INTERVAL generator.number DAY AS date
  FROM ( 

    SELECT 
     (@number  := @number + 1) AS number
    FROM (
      SELECT 0 UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9
    ) AS record_1
    CROSS JOIN (
      SELECT 0 UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9
    ) AS record_2
    CROSS JOIN (
      SELECT 0 UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9
    ) AS record_3
    CROSS JOIN (
      SELECT 0 UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9
    ) AS record_4
    CROSS JOIN ( SELECT @number := 0 ) AS init_user_param 
  ) AS generator
) AS dates 
WHERE 
   dates.date BETWEEN '2015-01-26' AND '2016-09-24'
 AND
   DAY(dates.date) = 27
```

**Result**

```
| number of days |
|----------------|
|             20 |
```

see demo http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c61cdb/9