# How can i used less than equal or between function FROM DUAL table?

Tags: mysql

Im trying to get the date from previous week to current and it seemd between or >= are not working here.

```
WITH curr_cyc_dt AS (
    SELECT BETWEEN TO_DATE ('20181228', 'yyyymmdd') AND TO_DATE ('20190104', 'yyyymmdd') cyc_dt 
    FROM DUAL
)
```

Answer (score 0):

BETWEEN does not work like that, it will not automagically generate a list of dates for you. It is a comparison operator that checks if a date belongs to a date interval.

The simplest way to generate a list of days for the last 7 days (until today included) :

```
WITH curr_cyc_dt AS (
    SELECT 
        CURDATE(),
        DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY), 
        DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 3 DAY), 
        DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 4 DAY), 
        DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 5 DAY), 
        DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 6 DAY), 
        DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)
    )
    ...
```

PS : FROM DUAL is superfluous in MySQL

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This one works for me, 'WITH curr_cyc_dt AS (SELECT TO_DATE ('20180622', 'yyyymmdd') cyc_dt FROM DUAL)", but I need to capture all the data dates,,, I also used lessthan equal sign but no luck

Comment: DUAL is an Oracle construct. I would also modify the query above to use CURDATE() instead of now unless you want the timestamp.  Also, setting the value prior to running the query "set mydate = CURDATE();" prior to running the query would allow you to evaluate @mydate instead of having to call the now() function multiple times.  There is a typo in the above:  CUR_DATE should be CURDATE or CURRENT_DATE.

Comment: One more thing - you can query against an existing table that has at least 7 rows in it and use the row number (which you can create as a variable in the select) with LIMIT 7 to use as the date_sub interval.  That way, if you need a month or two weeks or 10 days, you simply set the LIMIT clause to what you want.  You don't need anything from the "index" table you are querying other than the fact that it contains rows.  information_schema.columns works well for this. http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-row_number/

Comment: "DUAL is an Oracle construct" @TGray well since Oracle corporation is owning MySQL, using DUAL as dummy table since then is also support in MySQL.. But you are right GMB `FROM DUAL` is not needed in MySQL when selects are not working with tables.

Comment: Depends entirely on the version of MySQL involved.  That was not specified by the OP.

Answer (score 0):

```
set @myDate = CURDATE();
set @rowNumber = 0;

select date_sub(@myDate, interval @rowNumber day),
(@rowNumber := @rowNumber + 1) as rownum
  from information_schema.columns
LIMIT 7;
```

Comment: This query needs to have a `ORDER BY` clause also that guarantees the same results always.. SQL is by definition orderless what why `LIMIT 7` without using `ORDER BY` is not a valid way to always select the (same) "first 7" records.. Without `ORDER BY` SQL is free to pick anny record from the table and use it as the "first 7"

Comment: The order by is completely immaterial as no data is being retrieved.  The ONLY reason to query a table is as a shortcut to creating a row number. It could be any table that has 7 or more rows in it.  It's a "for" loop, essentially.

Comment: One more thing.  If you need to increase the "LIMIT" clause and use a variable, you can do that by removing the LIMIT clause, initiating a variable to contain your upper limit and then adding "WHERE @rowNumber < @upper_limit_variable".

Comment: "The order by is completely immaterial as no data is being retrieved." fair enougn i didn't notice that you didn't use data from that table " The ONLY reason to query a table is as a shortcut to creating a row number. It could be any table that has 7 or more rows in it. It's a "for" loop, essentially" yes i see now  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49898857/extract-total-occurance-of-billing-date-within-subscription-period-mysql/49899123#49899123) is how i would make a  MySQL number generator